# OneNote clipper for mac does seem to work

Tags: macos, safari-extension, onenote

For some reason OneNote clipper does not seem to work with safari. The extension works fine with Google chrome, firefox and ms edge but when it comes to safari, all efforts to clip a webpage to onenote end up in never never land!

I open a web page, click on 'clip to onenote', get a sign in popup, sign in using ms account, then nothing!!!

The exact same procedure works perfectly well with chrome and firefox. After sign in, another popup allows me to clip the page to onenote.

This is what I have done so far but to no avail:

1. Removed the button, and re-added the button and restarted macbook. Nothing works!
2. removed all cookies, removed 'clip to onenote', reinstalled 'clip to onenote', restarted macbook. Nothing happens!
3. un-checked 'block popup windows' in preferences, restarted macbook. Nothing happens!
4. re-checked 'block popup windows' in preferences, restarted macbook. Nothing happens!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I hit (potentially) the same problem a couple of months ago and traced it down to a combination of a few things:

1. I was using a private window in Safari.
2. When I clicked "Sign in" it was always launching a new tab (vs. popup window) to enter my credentials.
3. Tabs don't share credentials while in private mode. This is important because as a new tab (vs. popup window), the newly acquired credentials essentially go away when the tab closes.

For me, somehow in my preferences, under "Tabs", I had "Open pages in tabs instead of windows" set to "Always".  Switching it to "Automatically" seems to have fixed it.

Note that I realize in your description you mention a popup, so our situations may not be the same, but I figured I'd throw this out just in case.

Comment: I looked at my safari settings and the Tabs is set to automatically. However, I looked at the console and I found the following:10/10/15 16:47:04.581 Safari[740]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 276 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22